# Perl: Limiting characters on String Scalar variables

Tags: perl

I'm looking to ensure the number of characters on a given value are less than 1000. My function is unsure whether the value is an array, hash or scalar.

```
if (ref($value) eq 'SCALAR' && length($value) >= 1000 ) {
    return;
}
```

However, what happens if a number is passed in? Will I be unknowingly converting a number value to a string, and if so, is there a way of checking for a numeric value before checking its length?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your question, you are saying that you check the number of characters in a string, and that the variable containing it could also be a hash ref or array ref.

> ```
> if (ref($value) eq 'SCALAR' && length($value) >= 1000 ) {
>     return;
> }
> ```

However, your code does not check the length of the string or number. It assumes the variable might be a scalar reference, but then checks the length of the stringification of the scalar reference.

```
say \"asdf";
# SCALAR(0x268e7f8)

say length \"asdf";
# 17
```

This length should always be 17 on 64 bit systems, or 16 on 32 bit systems.

---

Once you actually dereference your scalar reference, the following will apply.

```
#                                     here  and here
#                                      ##        #
if (ref($value) eq 'SCALAR' && length( ${ $value } ) >= 1000 ) {
    return;
}
```

Since Perl has no types, the number will be treated as a string. Passing `"500"` is the same as passing `500`.

```
say length 500;
say length "500";

__END__
3
3
```

The variable itself will not be *converted*. You don't need to care about that at all. Your code is fine, as long as you contain the number in a scalar reference.

The scalar reference doesn't care if it references a string or a number.

```
say length ${ \500 };
say length ${ \"500" };

__END__
3
3
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$value` is a number as you claim, then `ref` will return an empty string, so execution will continue on to the next statement. You simply want

```
if (!ref($value) && length($value) >= 1000 ) {
    return;
}
```

This will take the length of the stringification of the `$value`, so `length(500)` is the same as `length("500")`, which is `3`.

---

If `$value` is a reference to a number, your code is wrong too. `length($value)` will take the length of the stringification of the reference. You want

```
if (ref($ref) eq 'SCALAR' && length($$ref) >= 1000 ) {
    return;
}
```

`$$ref` (short for `${ $ref }`) is the scalar to referenced by `$ref`.

(Note that it's very rare to have a reference to a scalar.)